# System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, nuget, health-check

I'm getting the below error while trying to execute an Azure functions project.

[image]

I have installed the following packages in my Azure functions project.
[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: could you please post the error and  .csproj in the code format .

Comment: refer this thread https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5894